# Adding Fields to Laravel 5.3 Registration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Trying to add some fields to the registration method in Laravel:auth. I've successfully added them to the view and the database (checked visually for the view, in phpMyAdmin for the DB), updated the controller's validator:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
      'type' => 'required|max:255', //new
      'fees' => 'required|max:255', //new
      'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

as well as updated the controller's create function:

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'type' => $data['type'], //new
    'fees' => $data['fees'], //new

    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);
```

And then topped it off by updating the Model:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'type','fees','password', 'remember_token',
];
```

But... well it doesn't work. The SQL created doesn't include my new fields and therefore returns an error as the DB doesn't have default values for them..

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'fees' doesn't have a
>   default value

Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're creating the `User`, you are not passing a value for field `222`.

Based on your `Validator` rules, this is a required field, so looks to be a mistake.

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'type' => $data['type'], //new
    'fees' => $data['fees'], //new
    '222' => $data['222'], // added

    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);
```

If you do not want to always save a value for `222`, either set the field to `nullable()` in your migration, or add a default (non null) value in your model.

Comment: That was a typo from my part on the thread.. fees = 222.. I had changed it to 222 so it would be easier to spot when debugging, seems I missed one.. The problem persists though..

Comment: The MySQL error says that your table contains a field called `222`. If that was a mistake, what's the error now?

Comment: Updated my question ^^' sorry!

Comment: Can we see your model definition? Have you made your new fields `fillable`?

Comment: I had put them in hidden by mistake.. Thanks for spotting that :)

Comment: Fields being `hidden` only stops them from being included when you call `toArray()` or `toJson()` on your model. That wouldn't stop your model from saving the values.

Comment: Well.. somehow today.. it did. as soon as I switched it around it worked. And if I switch it back, I get the same error. I'm thinking the registration uses a mass assignment for everything but the password & token?